# attributes vs this.attributes in the backbone 0.5.3 source codes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning the [tutorial on backbone source codes](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-backbone-js-source-code/). I am confused by the difference between `attributes` and `this.attributes` in the following codes. Can someone give some explanation? Thanks

I know that the current version is 1.3.3, but I am just curious about the syntax in the old source codes and what does it do.

```
Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
  var defaults;
  attributes || (attributes = {});
  if (defaults = this.defaults) {
    if (_.isFunction(defaults)) defaults = defaults.call(this);
    attributes = _.extend({}, defaults, attributes);
  }
  this.attributes = {};
  this._escapedAttributes = {};
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
  this.set(attributes, {silent : true});
  this._changed = false;
  this._previousAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);
  if (options && options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
  this.initialize(attributes, options);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want explained. Do you know what `this` means in JavaScript?

Comment: NO idea what ```this.attributes``` is for here (```this.attributes = {}; this._previousAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);```). ```attributes``` is used to set some fields in constructor function.

Comment: the `attributes` property of Backbone Models is used to store the model's fields internally. Those that you normally manipulate with the `get`, `set`, `unset` methods of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [**`this.attributes`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) is the **property** of a Backbone Model. It's the hash in which the model's data is kept. In the constructor, it is initialized as an empty object. You can access it from outside the class `modelInstance.attributes`.
- **`attributes`** is just the name of the **parameter** in which the initial data is passed to the model. It could be any name since it's a local variable in the constructor function. It can't be accessed from outside the constructor function.

When creating a new model instance, you can pass attributes to be set immediately.

```
var data = {
    initial: "data",
    id: "1234"
    // etc.
};

// here, data is passed into the `attributes` parameter.
var modelInstance = new Backbone.Model(data);
```

I changed the name of the local `attributes` variable to `initialData` to illustrate the concept. I also simplified a little the constructor function to better show what's going on.

```
Backbone.Model = function(initialData, options) {
    // Initializes properties
    this.attributes = {};
    this._escapedAttributes = {};
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');

    // Makes sure that the initialData variable is an object.
    if (!initialData) { // if it's a falsy value (undefined, 0, null, "")
        initialData = {}; // assign it a new object
    }

    // if the `defaults` property exists on this model class
    if (this.defaults) {
        var defaults;

        // and if it's a function
        if (_.isFunction(defaults)) {
            // call it and save the return value
            defaults = this.defaults();
        }

        // merge the defaults with the initial data, where any attribute present
        // in the initialData object overwrites the default value.
        initialData = _.extend({}, defaults, initialData);
    }

    // Apply the initialData to the `this.attributes` with all of other things
    // `set` does. No events are triggered since `silent` is set to true.
    this.set(initialData, { silent: true });

    // cancel the change flag since it's the initialization of a new instance.
    // Even if it changed from an empty object to the initialData value, it 
    // doesn't make sense to flag it as changed.
    this._changed = false;

    // a shallow copy of the attributes to compare to when changes are made.
    this._previousAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);

    // A model keeps a reference to the collection instance in which it was 
    // created (when passing raw data to a collection) to use its `url` property
    // when none are set in the model class.
    if (options && options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;

    // calls the initialize function, which is empty by default and is just 
    // a convinience for the developer to override.
    this.initialize(initialData, options);
};
```